# Can anyone tell me which piece of my CSS is causing a gap?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Within my Wordpress site I have a custom written PHP search. It appears within the Content section of specific pages via 'include' so it's a separate file.

http://www.glutenfreeireland.com/accommodation/find-accommodation/

The entire code for search and results appear within the DIV .wheretoeatsearchwrapper.
Unfortunately a large gap appears between the text "Step 1: Choose a Location:" and the first SELECT box. It is caused by the adverts on the right, which when removed, fix the problem. I understood the class wheretoeatsearchwrapper kept everything within that DIV, i.e. objects either side of wheretoeatsearchwrapper wouldn't affect content inside it?

This is the applicable CSS:

```
    .wheretoeatsearchwrapper {
        /*max-width: 490px;*/
        clear: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 10px; 
    }
    .wheretoeatsearchwrapper h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
      display: inline;
    }
    .searchlocation select {
      font-size: 95%;
      margin: 0.2em;
      float: left;
      clear: both;  
    }
    .steps {
      color: #339933;
      font-weight: bold;    
    }
    .searchvenuetype {
      font-size: 95%;
      margin: 4px;
      float: left;
      clear: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `clear:both;` on the `searchlocation select` element.

```
.searchlocation select {
    font-size: 95%;
    margin: 0.2em;
    float: left;
    clear: both; // Remove this
}
```

Comment: Just being more precise, I still answered it correctly and before you anyway.

Comment: Yes, and copied my answer :) to looks like mine :)

Comment: How was it copied? It's the OP's CSS, not yours, I just added it and put in a comment so that OP knew which line I was talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately it didn't work, the gap is still there.

Comment: It shouldn't be, I tested it using Chromes Developer Tools and removing it fixed the gap issue you're having.

Comment: My apologies, I think Quick Cache stopped my refresh from working. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove clear: both for .searchlocation select

```
.searchlocation select {
  font-size: 95%;
  margin: 0.2em;
  float: left;
  /*clear: both;*/
}
```